# NSURLSession: “CFNetworkDownload.tmp” couldn’t be moved to “images”

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I have an old app that uses NSURLConnection to download an image to the app. Today I tried to replace that old code with NSURLSession:

New Code:

```
/*download the images one by one in a for loop*/
-(void)downloadSingleSpecieImagesFromServer{
    [self generateImageURLList:NO];

    [leafletImageLoaderQueue removeAllObjects];
    numberOfHiResImageLeft = [uncachedHiResImageArray count];
    numberTotalToDownload = numberOfHiResImageLeft;

    for ( LeafletURL* aLeafletURL in uncachedHiResImageArray)
        {
            //// Do the same thing again, except set isThumb = NO. ////
            LeafletImageLoader* hiResImageLoader = [[LeafletImageLoader alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
            [leafletImageLoaderQueue addObject:hiResImageLoader]; // do this before making connection!! //

            [hiResImageLoader loadImage:aLeafletURL isThumbnail:NO   isBatchDownload:YES];

            //// Adding object to array already retains it, so it's safe to release it here. ////
            [hiResImageLoader release];
            uncachedHiResIndex++;
            NSLog(@"uncached hi res index: %ld, un cached hi res image array size: %lu", (long)uncachedHiResIndex, (unsigned long)
            [uncachedHiResImageArray count]);
    }
}

/*LeafletImageLoader.m */
- (void)loadImage:(LeafletURL*)leafletURLInput isThumbnail:(BOOL)isThumbnailInput isBatchDownload:(BOOL)isBatchDownload
{
    [self loadImage:leafletURLInput isThumbnail:isThumbnailInput isBatchDownload:isBatchDownload isRetina:NO];
}

- (void)loadImage:(LeafletURL*)leafletURLInput isThumbnail:(BOOL)isThumbnailInput isBatchDownload:(BOOL)isBatchDownload isRetina:(BOOL)isRetina
{

    isRetina_ = isRetina;

    self.leafletURL = leafletURLInput;
    self.isThumbnail = isThumbnailInput;
    NSString* location;
    if(self.isThumbnail){
        location = leafletURL.thumbnailLocation;
    }else{
        location = leafletURL.hiResImageLocation;
    }

    if ( ([location isEqualToString:kLocationServer] || (isBatchDownload && [location isEqualToString:kLocationResource])) && self.leafletURL.rawURL != nil )
    {
        NSLog(@"location: final loadimage called server");
        //// tell the delegate to get ride of the old image while waiting. ////
        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoaderWillBeginLoadingImage:)])
        {
            [delegate leafletImageLoaderWillBeginLoadingImage:self];
        }

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[leafletURL pathForImageOnServerUsingThumbnail:self.isThumbnail isRetina:isRetina]];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration * config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"myQueue"];
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:url];

        [downloadTask resume];

    }

    //// if not, tell the delegate that the image is already cached. ////
    else
    {
        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:)])
        {

            [delegate leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:self];

        }
    }
}
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location{

        //// save the downloaded image to disk ////
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if (isThumbnail)
        {
            leafletURL.thumbnailLocation = kLocationCache;
        }
        else
        {
            leafletURL.hiResImageLocation = kLocationCache;
        }

        // Filename to write to
        NSString* filePath = [leafletURL pathForImageAtLocation:kLocationCache isThumbnail:isThumbnail isRetina:NO];

        // If it's a retina image, append the "@2x"
        if (isRetina_) {
            filePath = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".jpg" withString:@"@2x.jpg"];
        }

        NSString* dir = [filePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

        [managedObjectContext save:nil];

        NSError* error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];


    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){

        [fileManager replaceItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] withItemAtURL:location backupItemName:nil options:NSFileManagerItemReplacementUsingNewMetadataOnly resultingItemURL:nil error:&error];

    }else{

        if([fileManager moveItemAtPath:location.path toPath:filePath error:&error])
        {
            if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:)])
            {
                [delegate leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:self];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoader:didFailWithError:)] )
            {
                [delegate leafletImageLoader:self didFailWithError:error];
            }
        }
    }
}
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes{
    NSLog(@"download task resumed!");
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"this is the error: %@", error.description);
    if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoader:didFailWithError:)] )
    {
        [delegate leafletImageLoader:self didFailWithError:error];
    }
}

/*LeafletImageManager.m */
- (void)leafletImageLoader:(LeafletImageLoader*)leafletImageLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{

    NSLog(@"ERROR Code %d: %@ for %@", error.code, [error localizedDescription], leafletImageLoader.leafletURL.rawURL);
    numberFailedToDownload++;

    if ( error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet )
    {
        [self cancel];
        //// Tell delegate to show error message. ////
        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didFailWithError:)])
        {
            [delegate request:self didFailWithError:&error];
        }
    }
    else if ( error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut )
    {
        NSLog(@"NSURLErrorTimedOut");
        UIAlertView* alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Slow Connection: Single Species Download Recommended"
                                                         message:@"Hi-Resolution images requires 250Mb of content to be downloaded, which cannot be completed. Do you wish to download only this species in Hi-Resolution?"
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               otherButtonTitles:@"Download", nil] autorelease];
        [alert show];

    }
    else 
    {
        //// Remove bad loader, and continue. ////

        if (leafletImageLoader.isThumbnail)
        {
            numberOfThumbnailLeft--;
        }
        else
        {
            numberOfHiResImageLeft--;
        }
        [leafletImageLoaderQueue removeObject:leafletImageLoader];
        numberRemovedFromQueue++;

        if ( [leafletImageLoaderQueue count] == 0 && numberRemovedFromQueue == numberTotalToDownload) {
            if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidBatchDownloadImages:)])
            {
                [delegate requestDidBatchDownloadImages:self];
            }
        }

        if ( [leafletImageLoaderQueue count] == 0 )
        {
            [self batchDownloadImagesFromServer:TRUE];
        }

        if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestdownloading:progress:thumbnailCount:hiResCount:)])
        {
            float progress = 1 - (float)[leafletImageLoaderQueue count] / numberOfImagesToDownload;
            NSInteger tc = numberOfImages - numberOfThumbnailLeft;
            NSInteger hc = numberOfImages - numberOfHiResImageLeft;
            [delegate requestdownloading:self progress:progress thumbnailCount:tc hiResCount:hc];
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, it finishes the download task, calling `didFinishDownloadingToURL` and then `didCompleteWithError` gets called, which of course calls `didCompleteWithError` in `LeafletImageManager.m`

The error code and message from `LeafletImageManager.m` is:

> ERROR Code 4: “CFNetworkDownload_vAMuqX.tmp” couldn’t be moved to
>   “images” because either the former doesn’t exist, or the folder
>   containing the latter doesn’t exist. for /species/Robinia
>   pseudoacacia/images/SAFV-RBD-01970.jpg

I added code to check that an image exists in `didFinishDownloadingToURL` and it indeed does. I'm assuming then that the issue is that the folder doesn't exist. I'm confused why that would be when I create the directory with `fileManager`

My old code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{   
    //// Check if it's valid image. ////
    //// If not, UIImage will be nil.////
    UIImage* theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mImageData];

    if(theImage)
    {       
        //// save the downloaded image to disk ////

        if (isThumbnail)
        {
            leafletURL.thumbnailLocation = kLocationCache;
        }
        else
        {
            leafletURL.hiResImageLocation = kLocationCache;
        }

        // Filename to write to
        NSString* filePath = [leafletURL pathForImageAtLocation:kLocationCache isThumbnail:isThumbnail isRetina:NO];

        // If it's a retina image, append the "@2x"
        if (isRetina_) {
            filePath = [filePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".jpg" withString:@"@2x.jpg"];           
        }

        NSString* dir = [filePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

        [managedObjectContext save:nil];

        NSError* error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dir withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

        if ( [mImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES] )
        {
            if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:)])
            {
                [delegate leafletImageLoaderDidFinishLoadingImage:self];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoader:didFailWithError:)] )
            {
                [delegate leafletImageLoader:self didFailWithError:error];
            }
        }
    }


    else
    {
        if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoader:didFailWithError:)] )
        {
            NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:kLeafletErrorDomain code:kErrorImageNotFound userInfo:nil];
            [delegate leafletImageLoader:self didFailWithError:error];
        }
    }

    [theImage release];

    [mImageData release];
    mImageData = nil;

    [mConnection release];
    mConnection = nil;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"leafletimageloader connection did fail with the error: %@", error);
    [mImageData release];
    mImageData = nil;

    [mConnection release];
    mConnection = nil;

    if( [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(leafletImageLoader:didFailWithError:)] )
    {
        [delegate leafletImageLoader:self didFailWithError:error];
    }
}
```

Comment: No chance this is a Mac app and the temp file is on a different volume, is there?  Because that could explain why moving the file would fail, where writing it at that location succeeds.

Comment: that...could absolutely explain it. I will look into this after my midterms hah